# LibreSSL: free memory allocated by tls_init()

Tags: c, libressl

When using LibreSSL's libtls, is it possible to free the memory that is allocated by `tls_init()`?

I found using valgrind that a simple program that only calls `tls_init()` code leaves 2058 blocks of memory "still reachable".  I am aware that "still reachable" memory is not strictly a memory leak and it will be cleaned up by the OS when the program exits...  But it makes identifying my own memory issues much more obnoxious.

OpenSSL's `SSL_library_init()` doesn't seem to have the same problem.

I'm on Linux with a source build from the libressl-portable github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also asked on the libressl mailing list.  [The answer is no, at least not with the current libtls API](https://marc.info/?l=libressl&m=152511457226266&w=2).

The current best alternative for memory testing with valgrind [is to use the `--suppressions` option](https://marc.info/?l=libressl&m=152519628620361&w=2).

Comment: Nice finding! For future reference it may be useful to also add a link to the relevant mail in the mailing list (if it's public).

Comment: Never mind, I found them and added them to the answer.